# Uploading a file stored in browser memory via ajax

Tags: ajax, filereader

Assume there are no cross-domain issues with the ajax calls to the server(s).

First, I am making an ajax call to grab the contents of a binary file (docx) from the server.  The contents are then stored in the browser memory.

Next, I need to make another ajax call to the server to upload the file contents along with other form fields.  The page may already contains the form, or the js can dynamically create the form (which would be hidden), or I can use the FormData object in the js code.

I can't figure out how to take file contents that are in memory and include them in a form POST call to upload the file along with the other form inputs.  Any idea how to do this?

I thought perhaps using the FileReader object I could do this, as I have seen where you can use FileReader.readAsBinaryString() on a blob or binary data, then have the onloadend trigger the form submit.

I would prefer to use jquery, but that is not necessary.